# Change default profile saving directory - Selenium Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using selenium with geckodriver, My goal is to use a pre-existing session's profile on a defined path rather than default directory `tmp`.

As I start session with a new profile:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
```

profile gets saved by default to directory `/tmp`

```bash
>>> os.system('ls -lt ../../../tmp')
total 25248
drwx------  2 root root     4096 Sep 20 11:10 tmpqzp6uf3c
```

I'd like to change the default directory `/tmp` to an another directory I define for any new profile.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial profile path parameter in the `FirefoxProfile([profile_directory])` constructor([document](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html?highlight=profile_directory)), but the firefox driver will create a temporary profile(directory) and copy the intial profile to it each time(see [Why Selenium always create temporary Firefox Profiles using Web Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521731/why-selenium-always-create-temporary-firefox-profiles-using-web-driver/40527704#40527704)), surely you can copy the temparory folder back like this post: [Python / Selenium / Firefox: Can't start firefox with specified profile path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350778/816109)

Answer (score 0):

Default location for temporary are defined by environnement variable `$TMPDIR`, see https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Profiles.html

I set up env variable `TMPDIR=/opt/Projects/01_Twitter/tmp` , sourced `~/.bashrc`, lunched a new session:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
```

now profile is savec under `$TMPDIR`:

```bash
>>> os.system('ls -lt /opt/Projects/01_Twitter/tmp')
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 1666 Sep 21 10:29 rust_mozprofileAGsZ26
...
```

When I close driver:

```bash
driver.close()
```

Profile is well saved in `$TMPDIR`, but Firefox keeps creating temporary files for the profile

```bash
>>> os.system('ls -lt /opt/Projects/01_Twitter/tmp')
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 1666 Sep 21 10:31 rust_mozprofileGnbPp5
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 1666 Sep 21 10:29 rust_mozprofileAGsZ26
...
```

The best option is to copy profile into a persisted directory:

```bash
>>> os.system('cp -r /opt/Projects/01_Twitter/tmp/rust_mozprofileAGsZ26 .')
```

and quit the driver

```bash
driver.quit()
```